# GreenDao - Android - How to listen to DB change using GreenDao

Tags: android, observer-pattern, greendao, greendao3

I'm using GreenDao 3 and I'd like to know what is the `URI` to be used to listen to DB changes.
I'm using this code:

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://" + BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + "/table1");
getContext().getContentResolver().registerContentObserver(uri, false, mObserver);
```

However, after an insert/updated or some change on table1, nothing happen at `onChange` method on `mObserver` variable.

Am I doing something wrong? Is the URI wrong? What should I do to make it work?

Thanks

Comment: and of course you are updating it via ContentProvider?

Comment: How using GreenDao 3?

Comment: I have no idea ... but `registerContentObserver` is part of ContentProvider API ... Why do you think that GreenDao will automagically use it? Obviously it will "not work" until someones call  `ContentREsolver.notifyChange` with the uri which match your uri